# Why if statement still be excuted when condition is false?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Code is shown below, value-row+i is obviously -1. But the following statement still  excutes. Problem is the first if in enlarge function.

```
void enlarge(queue<vector<int>> &slv, vector<int> &v, int n)
{
    auto row = v.size();

    int rec = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    {
        int value = v[i];
        rec |= 1 << value;
        //int s = (value - row);
        if (value - row + i >= 0)   
            rec |= 1 << (value - row + i);
        if (value + row - i < n)    
            rec |= 1 << (value + row - i);
    }
    vector<int> vt;
    int bitPosi = 0;
    while (bitPosi < n)
    {
        if (!(rec & 1))
        {
            v.push_back(bitPosi);
            slv.push(v);
            v.pop_back();
        }
        rec >>= 1;
        bitPosi++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code belongs in the question as text, not an image.

Comment: Post all code here directly as text as an [mcve]

Comment: Are you ignoring warnings about signed v unsigned comparisons?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. It happened because row is declared as an auto variable and is inferred as size_t. When converted to int, row loses precision.

Comment: Not a loss of precision. The expression is converted to `size_t`, which is unsigned. Therefore, any value other than 0 will be >= 0.